# How can i call through app automatically?

Tags: objective-c

Hi can anyone suggest me How can I call through app automatically I mean I used following code in my app.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123-4567-890"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Its working properly and after call end its returning back to app too but problem is it will not take call event automatically,we have to click call button.so is there any way to call without giving any user interaction??
Thanks in advnce...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123-4567-890"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

The `telprompt` URL scheme is designed to ask the user to confirm the call. If you just use `tel`, the call will be initiated immediately.

Comment: But if I use this, after my call ends it will not return back to app this my problem.I have to make call automatically and should return back to app after call ends.Any idea...?? Thanks a lot..